# Problem happen after integrate FanMenu framework in xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have tried to integrate FanMenu framework to my project, and then I got the following error and my app is not working

```
:-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/amira/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/star-gvkwjukrellysodofwfcqkjcyhwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FanMenu/FanMenu.framework/Info.plist':
1) Target 'FanMenu' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Volumes/Data/Work/StarApp/iOS-user-Registration-master/Pods/FanMenu/Sources/Info.plist' to '/Users/amira/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/star-gvkwjukrellysodofwfcqkjcyhwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FanMenu/FanMenu.framework/Info.plist'
2) Target 'FanMenu' (project 'Pods') has process command with output '/Users/amira/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/star-gvkwjukrellysodofwfcqkjcyhwo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FanMenu/FanMenu.framework/Info.plist'
```

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Workspace Settings -> Build system -> Legacy build system.

I also faced the same problem. After change the settings. Everything is good now